# asp.net Problems with login : login failed for user NT Authority\Anonymous Logon

Tags: asp.net

Im getting the following error when I try to login to web page with a valid username and password:

> Oops. The error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

This is my web.config :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXFORUM" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" 
                                                    timeout="30" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Anyone know what this error mean?

Comment: could you provide some more details? like the asp.net version and sql server authentication type and the webserver on which the app is run like cassini or IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach the stack trace maybe?   The "Oops" in the message makes me think that some code is catching the real error and returning a friendly error message.  Try putting the breakpoint in there to get the stack trace.

If I had to take a wild guess,  I'd say your code is trying to connect to the backend SQL Server database using integrated auth.  In this is case your web application is connecting using the web server process account and failing.   Try changing the connection string to use a valid SQL Server user name and password to see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the allow users element after the deny element, see example

```
   <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
   </authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to check your web.config file and make sure one of these is part of the db connection string:

Trusted Connection=false
OR
Integrated Security=True

Answer (score 0):

Remove "Integrated Security=true;" from Web.Config of the application resolved this for me.

.net 4.0
WCF application
IIS7 (hosted on server1)
SQL 2005 (hosted on server2

Hope that helps someone.
Scott